# issue in sending realtime data from esp32 to Django webpage

Tags: python, django, tcp, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am having trouble in sending data from tcp client in my esp32 board to my python django server,I am not familiar with setting channels in Django ,is there a way so that i can send the data and display in my page?

Answer (score 1):

in order for your microcontroller (esp32) communicate with your own server side code first you need to define protocol you're going to use:

A. TCP:
TCP relies on IP which provides address to communicate between computers. TCP/IP is a basis for internet and other networks.

B. HTTP:
HTTP mostly used by browser (IE, Google Chrome). It rides on top of TCP which provides a safe and reliable link between two computers because if packet get lost - it can be safely re-transmitted.

After deciding protocol that you're going to use now you need suitable server side code. In python there are several library / framework that you can use:

A. HTTP: 
Django, Flask, AIOHTTP (all of this supports sending and receiving JSON (REST)), I preferably use one of this framework for my IoT Projects.

B. TCP: If your microcontroller is very minimal and doesn't support HTTP/JSON, you can use a simple SocketServer or Tornado TCP Server. Don't worry even though communication between your board and server done through TCP you can still import django's libraries and use django's ORM.

Comment: I mean the issue is that i am not able to integrate SocketServer with Django is there a way to do so?